# How to calculate a sum conditionally based on the values of two other columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Feels like this may be a basic, but I cannot find a way to do this with `sumifs`.

I've got four columns in one table, representing the workload of an employee like this:

| Job | Employee # 1 | Employee # 2 | Workload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job 1 | Bob | Jane | 5 |
| Job 2 | Bob |  | 2 |
| Job 3 | Jane | Susan | 3 |
| Job 4 | Susan |  | 2 |

I'd like to output total workflow results to a second sheet for each employee based on a specialized formula. In English, the forumla would be:

Calculate the total workload for each employee.
- For each job that includes that includes employee named "X" and no assigned teammate, use the job's corresponding workload value.
- For each job that includes that includes employee named "X" and has an assigned teammate, reduce the corresponding workload value by 50%.

So with the given table above, I'd want an output like this:

| Employee Name | Workload |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 4.5 |
| Jane | 4 |
| Susan | 3.5 |

```
Math:
Bob = ((job_1 / 2) + job_2)
Jane = ((job_1 / 2) + (job_3 / 2))
Susan = ((job_3 / 2) + job_4)
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?
Functions like `sumifs` seem to only let me set criteria to sum or not sum a value. But I cannot find a clear way to sum only 50% of a value based on a condition in a separate column.

Comment: Hi joe-ellis double check the math for `Jane 3` it should be `Jane  4` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=LAMBDA(name,SUMIFS(D2:D5,B2:B5,name,C2:C5,"")+SUMIFS(D2:D5,B2:B5,name,C2:C5,"<>")/2+SUMIFS(D2:D5,C2:C5,name)/2)("Bob")
```

The math is

- `SUM` D, if B is `Bob` and C is empty and
- `SUM` half of D if B is `Bob` and C is not empty and
- `SUM` half of D, if C is `Bob`.

Or the same logic via query:

```
=QUERY(
    {
      QUERY(B1:D5,"Select B,sum(D) where C is null group by B");
      QUERY(B1:D5,"Select C,sum(D)/2 where C is not null group by C");
      QUERY(B1:D5,"Select B,sum(D)/2 where C is not null group by B")
    },
    "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where not Col1 contains 'Employee' group by Col1"
)
```

However, note that we're assuming title  contains `Employee` and  no other names contain `Employee`.

| Employee # 1 | sum sum Workload |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 4.5 |
| Jane | 4(Incorrect in the question) |
| Susan | 3.5 |

Comment: I ended up using your lambda example, which worked great! I did not realize I'd be able to simply define the different cases with `sumifs` and then just add them up, but that does make sense now that I think about it.

Comment: @JoeEllis uumm men [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857025/19529694) is also a `LAMBDA` sloution take a look.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula({ "Employee Name", "Workload";
              QUERY(
 QUERY({LAMBDA(a,b,c,d,k, {b,a,{d/k};c,a,{d/k}} )
             (A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,D2:D,
              BYROW(B2:C, LAMBDA(c, IF(COUNTA(c)=0,,IF(COUNTA(c)=1,1,2)))))},
        "Select (Col1),sum(Col3) Group by Col1" ,0), "Where Col1 <> '' ",0)})
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`COUNTA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991) - [**`SUM`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You don't need to be elaborate. Just a brief explanation(one or two sentences) on the very basics of how it works will go a long way in improving the long term quality of this post.

Comment: Yes indeed, I m taking on more than I can handle, lately.

Comment: I would personally recommend using the time to add formula links to add some explanations. Formula links can be googled. Explanations on the other hand,  would take a long time to understand by viewers. Even a single sentence is better than "try this" or "use this formula", IMO. FWIW, I didn't get what  your formula does

Comment: It's not like I didn't do this either. I added a lot of code only answers, even without "try this". My answers would contain nothing but pure code, no pictures, no extra words. Nothing but code blocks. I  changed over a very long time.  You're free to do what you're doing currently. No one's going to bother you though.

Comment: I have to say this given solution is more mind puzzling than yours @TheMaster

Comment: Thank's @marikamitsos smash that arrow.