# How can I add the results from 3 query statements?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

To get the number of flight cancellations in any given month, I'm using a COUNTIFS statement, as follows:

`=COUNTIFS(QF_Data_2022!C$2:C,"September",QF_Data_2022!E$2:E,"canceled",QF_Data_2022!F$2:F,"MIA")`

Where Col_C is the month, Col_E is the flight status, and Col_F is the airport code.

It works great.

But in an effort to obtain figures that reflect more than a single month (i.e. Q3), the approach of adding the following conditions on the same column (C) is not working:

`(...QF_Data_2022!C$2:C,"September",QF_Data_2022!C$2:C,"August",QF_Data_2022!C$2:C,"July"...)`

So I've moved to a QUERY function:

`=QUERY(QF_Data_2022!A2:R, "SELECT COUNT(C) WHERE C='July' OR C='August' OR C='September' AND E='CANCELED' AND F='MIA' LABEL COUNT(C) '' ")`

BUT the result gives me an integer that is FAR too high (e.g. 3770 results out of 5800 rows, when the actual number should be about 164).

So, is something like the following possible:

```
SUM = QUERY 1 + QUERY 2 + QUERY 3
```

Or is there a better approach altogether?

Comment: Just group them: `WHERE (C='July' OR C='August' OR C='September') AND E='CANCELED' AND F='MIA' LABEL COUNT(C) ''`

Comment: You can also add three countifs  similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73855292/how-to-calculate-a-sum-conditionally-based-on-the-values-of-two-other-columns/73855616#73855616)